# How to append the column names once checked with dataframe in python

Tags: python, list, frame

I have a list of data frame columns. I need to check those names with the data frame column names if it matches then it should place the d-type names into one list and d-type object names into another list I have tried but can't able to convert them into lists. How do I do it?

```
Input: 
col_lst = ['bc','fgc ','drt']
df=
   abc bc  fgc drt  
0  0   q   d  3  
1  0   g   t  1  
2  0   a   g  4 
3  0   d   c  5  
4  0   h   b  6
```

My code:

```
x=[]
for col in df:
    for i in col_lst:
        if i in col:
            if df[col].dtype == float or df[col].dtype == int:
                     c_int=[]
                     for i in col: c_int.append(list(i.split(","))
            elif df[col].dtype == object:
                     c_obj=[]
                     for i in col: c_obj.append(list(i.split(","))
```

the output Iam getting:

```
c_int = [['d'],['r'],['t']]
c_obj=
[['b'], ['c']]
[['f'],['g'],['c']]
```

the output I need:

```
c_int =['drt']
c_obj =['bc','fgc']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is.

```
col_lst = ['bc','fgc','drt']                                                                                         
df = pd.DataFrame({'abc':[0,0,0,0,0], 'bc':['q','g','a','d','h'], 'fgc':['d','t','g','c','b'], 'drt':[3,1,4,5,6]})   
common = set(col_lst).intersection(set(df.columns))                                                                  
c_int=[]                                                                                                             
c_obj = []                                                                                                           
for col in common:                                                                                                   
    if df[col].dtype==float or df[col].dtype == int:                                                                 
        c_int.append(col)                                                                                            
    elif df[col].dtype == object:                                                                                    
        c_obj.append((col))                                                                                          
print(c_int)                                                                                                         
print(c_obj)
```

prints:

```
['drt']
['fgc', 'bc']
```

Comment: No problem. Remember the trick with set intersection. It’s a useful way to find common members without iterating.